# Need help understanding object not declared in scope

Tags: c++, class, object, scope

I wrote down an example code to try to replicate the error I am getting in a school project about the scope of an object:

In file: classTest.cpp

```
#include "headerone.h"
#include "headertwo.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ClassOne* pntrObj1 = new ClassOne;

    ClassTwo* pntrObj2 = new ClassTwo;

    pntrObj1->testClassOne();

    return 0;
}
```

In file: headerone.h

```
#ifndef HEADERONE_H
#define HEADERONE_H

#include "headertwo.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ClassOne {
    public:
        void testClassOne() {
            cout << "One Worked\n";
            pntrObj2->testClassTwo();
        }
};

#endif
```

In file: headertwo.h

```
#ifndef HEADERTWO_H
#define HEADERTWO_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ClassTwo {
    public:
        void testClassTwo() {
            cout << "Two Worked";
        }
};

#endif
```

To be clear, the error is: pntrObj2 was not declared in this scope. The error comes from the file headerone.h

If I had to guess, I need to somehow pass the reference but I am not sure where to start for that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Guessing your way into c++ is a really easy way to get turned off it. You should really start with a good book: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `pntrObj2` is only visible inside the scope in which it was declared, in this case your function `main()`. In other words, only code inside the curly braces of `main()` would be able to use the name `pntrObj2` to reference that variable. However you can pass that value to other pieces of code by making it the argument of a function call.

So maybe what you want to do is add an argument to the `testClassOne()` method, so you can pass in the value of `pntrObj2`. So `pntrObj1->testClassOne();` would become `pntrObj1->testClassOne(pntrObj2);`, and where you define `testClassOne` you can add a corresponding parameter. I'll let you figure this out so as to not completely do your homework for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you include your file a lot of time and in testClassOne function, you do not declare pntrObj2

use

```
 void testClassOne() {
            cout << "One Worked\n";
            ClassTwo* pntrObj2 = new ClassTwo()
            pntrObj2->testClassTwo();
        }
```

insteed of

```
 void testClassOne() {
            cout << "One Worked\n";
            pntrObj2->testClassTwo();
        }
```